# Redirected to IIS7 whenever I try to access Fiverr on Google Chrome after Windows 10 Update

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10, iis-7

This weird thing is happening to me where I am redirected to IIS7 whenever i try to access Fiverr on Google Chrome. This does not seem to be happening on Microsoft Edge. I am running windows 10 x64. I have checked hosts file and it seems all right, also ISS is disabled under windows features. This is baffling

[image: here is the image]